# In Java, how do you query the nested field in elasticsearch according to ID?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
ScoreMode mode=ScoreMode.Total;
        SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = 
                    client.prepareSearch() 
                          .setIndices("commons")
                          .setTypes("webpage")
                          //.fields("id")
                          .setSize(10000)
                          .setQuery(QueryBuilders
                                  .nestedQuery("imgSource", 
                                          QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                  .must(
                                          QueryBuilders.matchQuery(
                                                  "id","48ca52e0d733c5093c08aa4df0b073f7")
                                          ),mode));
```

this is my code,but result is null,So I don't know if I made a mistake...

Comment: Please share field mapping and exact path of ID field

Answer (score 2):

As per [java api for nested queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-joining-queries.html#java-query-dsl-nested-query), Your code snippet should look something like below:

> Suppose I want to query **name** field inside nested document **child**, then code snippet will be:

```
ScoreMode mode=ScoreMode.Total;
    SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = 
                client.prepareSearch() 
                      .setIndices(INDEX_NAME)
                      .setTypes(TYPE_NAME)
                      .setQuery(QueryBuilders
                              .nestedQuery("child", 
                                      QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                              .must(
                                      QueryBuilders.matchQuery(
                                              "child.name","CHILD_NAME")
                                      ),mode));
```

So, your **match query** is incorrect, it should be **imgSource.id**